# Listbox manual DrawItem big font size

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to draw items that end of them is an `*` character in red (and remove that `*` character) and draw other items in black color.

this is my code:

```
    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground() ; //Draw our regular background
        if (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Right(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 1) == "*")
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(),1,listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString().Length - 1), e.Font, Brushes.Red, e.Bounds);    //Draw the item text in red!
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds); //Draw the item text in its regular color
        }
    }
```

Also `DrawMode` property of the listbox is set to `OwnerDrawVariable`.

My code is working fine when the font of listbox is the default font.

But When I change the font size from 8.25 (default size) to 14, half of the text draws on the listbox. like this:
[image: My listbox when size is 14!]

But with default font size, everything is correct.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to handle the [MeasureItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem.aspx) event and set the height of the items there:

```
private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
     e.ItemHeight = listBox1.Font.Height;
}
```

Comment: I have used `e.ItemHeight = listBox1.Font.Height;` and it works well. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, I'll update my answer with your comment so it doesn't depend on an additional custom `ListBoxFontItem` class.